# Showing Multiple PPTs in one UIWebView on iPhone

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, powerpoint

In my current app, I have a `UITableView` that shows hundreds of PPT files that are stored within the app.  When one is clicked, a new view with a `UIWebView` in it loads that PPT file into the webView.  What I was wondering is if it is possible for me to use an accessoryView to select multiple PPT files, and then load all of those PPT files into one UIWebView, allowing them to scroll from the first selected into the second, and so on.

Comment: This is not a solution of your problem but another way to achieve solution. You can create separate control to navigate through multiple PPTs selected by user and put it along with the UIWebView (like horizontal tray in bottom or any where else when user can easily access it).

Comment: @KTPATEL I get what you're saying but looking for something a little different, as doing that on a 4 or 4S would really kill the screen space.

Comment: Is the question about the multiple selection of the source or the multiple display of the result?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Actually, both.  I have an idea in mind for how to select multiple objects from the tableview, but absolutely no idea of the way to string all the selected PPTs together in one view.

Comment: Can you point me to a sample PPT file, similar to the ones you will use?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Don't have any actually uploaded online.  However it is very basic PPT file, most with one slide and just some text on it, sometimes a background image.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Got one uploaded http://www.316apps.com/Still.ppt

Comment: Thank you. I had devised and built a solution using multiple webview, chained by constraints. The excerpt of code below works, I will delete these comments shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use multiple UIWebViews**

Each PPT may have different width or aspect ratio. Combining all the PPT into a single one may seem like a good idea, but may not be practical.

The same can be said about combining multiple web pages: you may run into conflicting globals, such as background color or worse, encoding.

By choosing to adopt a programmatic impression of continuity, you will avoid all these issues and more, and additionally be able to display different types of documents as well: PDF, PPT, WEB, all in a continuous manner.

---

**Vertical Option**

1. Instead of adding a `UIWebview` to your container view, add a `UIScrollView`. In turn, position your webviews inside the scroller, with chained vertical constraints.
2. Load each `UIWebView` content individually:

   ```
   aWebView.delegate = self
   if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Still", withExtension: "ppt") {
       awebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
   }
   ```
3. Modify the intrinsic size of each webview so that it takes the whole space available. If you do this in the delegate, you basically let the OS do all the calculations for you, and just gather the values after the fact:

   ```
   func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
       if let flow = webView as? FlowWebView {
           flow.w.constant = self.view.bounds.width
           flow.h.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
       }
   }
   ```

For simplicity, I created a simple wrapper so that I can access intrinsic constraints easily, but you could just as easily rebuild constraints on the fly:

```
class FlowWebView: UIWebView {
    @IBOutlet var h: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var w: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

I have tried the above code in iOS 9, Xcode 7, Swift. The only additions you will need are:

- orientation change
- Scale pages to Fit

---

**Horizontal Option**

The horizontal option is similar (uses a separate `UIWebView` for each content), only are laid horizontally in the `UIScrollView` and can have the added clarity of a page view controller.

It requires a fixed height (less computation), and a predictable width (n x views). Swipe vertically through each PPT, and horizontally to go from one to the next.

Comment: I've not used Swift for anything just yet, so having a bit of trouble following the flow of the code.  Do I still just have one webView, or do I have a different webView for each bit of code?

Comment: The idea is to create 1 web view per document, and then place each of these webvews in a `UIScrollView` one below the other if you want to scroll vertically, or side-by-side if you want to scroll horizontally. You let the `NSLayoutConstraint` position all your web views, and once the content is loaded, you set the intrinsic height of each webview to the height of its content. This, in turn, will dimension your outer scrollview to fit all content exactly, giving the impression of a single, seamless view.

Comment: I'm just not seeing how I tell it how many documents selected, nor how to set up that many web views.

Comment: **3 questions**: **1** Can I assume that you will, at some point, have the URLs you need to load in an Array? **2** Do you prefer vertical layout (each PPT atop the other? **3** Can you confirm that once displayed, the content of PPT will not change until view goes back?

Comment: The power point files are all stored locally in the main bundle. Prefer vertical. Content will not change until goes back